# How do I use a variable name as the name of a csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
myfile = open(Class".csv","a+")
```

I am trying to set whats in Class as the name of the csv file but it comes up with a syntax error. Can someone advise me on how to fix this issue.

Comment: This is very unclear. What is "in Class"? Show that definition.

Comment: `open("{}.csv".format(Class),"a+")` is *probably* what you're after. Still, you can't expect people to be able to help when you don't clarify what exactly `Class` is.

Comment: Syntax error is due to bad string concatenation : `Class + ".csv"`

Comment: @DanielRoseman Class is filled by an input from the user

Comment: Please *show* that code. And also learn the basics of Python syntax.

Comment: @GrégoryBourgin now I receive the following error:                                            
                                                                                                            
 myfile = open(Class + ".csv","a+")
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'str'

Comment: Class = input("What class are you in?")

Comment: sorry for the poor layout and wording of this question this is my first time using this website.

Answer (score 1):

First string concatenation needs a '+' : `Class + ".csv"`

Plus, if `Class` is a variable, you should rename it since it's a reserved keyword :

https://docs.python.org/2.5/ref/keywords.html

Answer (score 0):

```
filename = raw_input()
fullpath = str(filename) + ".csv"

myfile = open(fullpath , "a+")
```

I hope this helps.